# .htaccess - How to add http://www. on multiple conditions

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to know how do I write the following htaccess so that it does the following:

- If the website link has no `http://www.` it'll add `http://www.` to the link.
- If the website link has just `www.` it'll change it to `http://www.`
- If the website link has just `http://` it'll change it to `http://www.`

I've tried doing the .htaccess code as I've enabled it to load as I'm using Apache 2.4.7 on Ubuntu.

Comment: conditions 2 and 3 have nothing related to mod_rewrite. as the first one in terms of the links in html page. mod_rewrite works with requests made to Apache server, not with the format of links in the returned data. Also, what is the difference between 1 and 3?

Comment: mod_rewrite also doesn't do anything to *links* on your website. It can only dynamically rewrite incoming requests. Your question suggests that you might be misunderstanding its purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this now by installing a2enmod with my htaccess.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that you used `a2enmod` to install something? This command just enables an Apache module, and won't do any rewriting itself. Did you do `a2enmod rewrite`?